# Safari always shows the bookmarks window

Tags: mac, safari

Whenever I open Safari, the bookmarks/saved for later window is always shown on the right side. How can I disable this? I can't seem to find such setting.

Answer (score 0):

Start Safari. Go to Edit -> preferences. Under the general tab you can specify your start page.